# Is it possible to define functions globally in Lua's table

Tags: lua

How to define functions into lua's table? I try this code but doesn't work.
I want to use `table:myfunc()`.

```
local myfunc
myfunc = function(t)
  local sum = 0
  for _, n in ipairs(t) do
    sum = sum + n
  end
  return sum
end

mytable = {
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
}

print(myfunc(mytable)) -- 45
```

I think `myfunc` has not problem.

```
table.myfunc = myfunc

print(mytable:myfunc())
-- lua: main.lua:18: attempt to call method 'myfunc' (a nil value)
-- stack traceback:
--         main.lua:18: in main chunk
--         [C]: ?
```

`print(mytable)` shows `table: 0x9874b0`, but it is not defined function to the table?

```
mytable.myfunc = myfunc
print(mytable:myfunc()) -- 45
```

This worked. Is it the only prefer way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of ways to define a function within a table.

I think the problem with your first code is that you have this:

```
table.myfunc = myfunc
```

where it should be:

```
mytable.myfunc = myfunc
```

In your case `mytable.myfunc` is nil as you never assigned a value to it

You could just write

```
local mytable = {}


function mytable.myfunction()end
```

or

```
mytable.myfunction = function()end
```

or

```
mytable["myfunction"] = function()end
```

or define myfunc separately and assign it to mytable.myfunc later like you did

If you want to access other table members from your function I recommend defining the function like that:

```
function mytable:myfunc()end
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
function mytable.myfunc(self)end
```

If you do so you can access mytable's member trough the keyword `self`

In your case it would end up like:

```
function mytable:myfunc()
  local sum = 0
  for _, n in ipairs(self) do
    sum = sum + n
  end
  return sum
 end
```

So you don't need the function parameter t anymore and you can run the desired `mytable:myfunc()`
Otherwise you would have to write `mytable:myfunc(mytable)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't noticed lua tables aren't unique... `print(table); print({})` prints `table: 0x21927a0 table: 0x2198450` there is no way to create a new table from `table`, right?

Comment: what do you mean by create a new table from table? tables are created by assiging = {}. table is just a table that contains table manipulation methods

Comment: @jackson555 explain what you plan to do and I can tell you can do it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I thought `{}` is assignable to defined to the table. I totally misunderstood of the behavior...

Answer (score -1):

```
table.myfunc = myfunc    
print(mytable:myfunc())
```

This cannot work, because mytable has no member called myfunc, table does.
you would either have to write

```
table.myfunc = myfunc -- assign myfunc to TABLE (not the same as mytable)
print(table.myfunc(mytable)) -- as with most other functions in table
```

or

```
mytable.myfunc = myfunc -- assign myfunc to MYTABLE
print(mytable:myfunc()) -- syntactic sugar for print(mytable.myfunc(mytable))
```

also, you can just define the function as either

```
function mytable:myfunc() -- syntactic sugar for mytable.myfunc(self)
    -- do something
    -- use "self" to access the actual table
end
```

or

```
function table.myfunc(t)
    -- do something
end
```

Comment: I think the last one is close to my plan.

Comment: I don't like the idea of adding functions to Lua's standard libraries. I'd rather create my own and set the standard library I wish to extend as its metatable. I prefer keeping standard and my stuff separate to avoid any confusion.
Other than that table's functions are for all tables whereas any function you add like his sum function is not!!! it is specific for one particular use case of a lua table

Comment: @jackson555 just tell us what you plan to do. Assigning functions to table is very bad practice.

Comment: @Piglet I know monkey patching is bad practice but I wanted to add `map`, `reduce` or `inspect` very specific functions to the table. It's like a `local floor = math.floor`. I don't have a plan called `myfunc` or what ever function to the lua table. And I will learn about metatable you pointed...

Comment: @jackson555 read something about OOP in Lua. I think this is what you need. tables with different contents but same functions. create local tables in some kind of constructor, set its metatable to your "base class" table and return it. then just use the constructor instead of {} to easily get new tables with your desired functions.